# Using "Any" or "Contains" when context not saved yet

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

Why isn't the exception triggered? Linq's "Any()" is not considering the new entries?

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();

foreach (string email in {"asdf@gmail.com", "asdf@gmail.com"})
{
   Person person = new Person();
   person.Email = email;

   if (db.Persons.Any(p => p.Email.Equals(email))
   {
       throw new Exception("Email already used!");
   }

   db.Persons.Add(person);
}

db.SaveChanges()
```

Shouldn't the exception be triggered on the second iteration?

The previous code is adapted for the question, but the real scenario is the following:
I receive an excel of persons and I iterate over it adding every row as a person to db.Persons, checking their emails aren't already used in the db. The problem is when there are **repeated emails in the worksheet itself (two rows with the same email)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - queries (by design) are only computed against the data source.  If you want to query in-memory items you can also query the `Local` store:

```
if (db.Persons.Any(p => p.Email.Equals(email) || 
    db.Persons.Local.Any(p => p.Email.Equals(email)  )
```

However - since YOU are in control of what's added to the store wouldn't it make sense to check for duplicates in your code instead of in EF?  Or is this just a contrived example?

Also, throwing an exception for an already existing item seems like a poor design as well - exceptions can be expensive, and if the client does not know to catch them (and in this case compare the message of the exception) they can cause the entire program to terminate unexpectedly.

Comment: I will try the Local thing, didn't know about it! (the exception was just for showing purposes)

Answer (score 1):

A call to `db.Persons` will always trigger a database query, but those new Persons are not yet persisted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine if you look at the data in debug, you'll see that the new person isn't there on the second iteration. If you were to set MyContext db = new MyContext() again, it would be, but you wouldn't do that in a real situation.

What is the actual use case you need to solve? This example doesn't seem like it would happen in a real situation.

If you're comparing against the db, your code should work. If you need to prevent dups being entered, it should happen elsewhere - on the client or checking the C# collection before you start writing it to the db.

Comment: I adapted the post so that it would be easier to read. What I need in real life is to parse a excel of persons and add every row to db.Persons, checking that the email isn't already taken in the db. The problem is that within the excel there can be two persons with the same email.